# Sublime Text snippet doesn't work in .scss files

Tags: sass, code-snippets, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I have the following saved in ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User as `sass_mq.sublime-snippet`:

```xml
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
    @include respond-min() {}
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>mq</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>source.sass</scope>
</snippet>
```

I got `source.sass` by pressing cmd + opt + p and looking at the status bar.

It works in all other file types if I remove the scope, but never in .scss files.

Is my syntax wrong?

Comment: Your snippet appears to work as is for me in Sublime Text 2...

Comment: @cimmanon The OP is using ST3...

Comment: Works for me in Sublime Text 3 (build 3059).

Comment: I'd forgotten about this! I think it was conflicting with the Hayaku package and I was able to find some shortcuts that it does work with e.g. `//` and `./`